# php replace these special characters (ms word generated single quotes) in string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

php replace these special characters (ms word autogenerated single quotes) in string

this kind of quote -> ‘
and this -> ’ 
should become simple single quote like this -> '

eg:
$string = " ‘o Really ’o Brian ";

should be

" 'o Really 'o Brian "

Comment: google is your friend, so am i, but google is less creepy

Comment: i found preg_replace with regex but in regex i cannot select just these two single quotas